# Yelp API "Bearer does not match"

Tags: php, authorization, bearer-token, yelp-fusion-api

This is one of the most confusing errors I've ever encountered because this is supposed to be super simple. I'm trying to connect to the Yelp API. I've created an App and obtained my "API Key". From there I:

1. Went to postman, selected "Bearer Token" as the Authorization type, copied and pasted my enter API Key, and ran the test.
2. Used Yelp's PHP sample code from here: https://github.com/Yelp/yelp-fusion/blob/master/fusion/php/sample.php with my copied and pasted API Key. I then ran the code.

Both tests returned the same error:

```
Fatal error: Curl failed with error #400: {"error": {"code": "VALIDATION_ERROR", "description": "'Bearer' does not match '^(?i)Bearer [A-Za-z0-9\\\\-\\\\_]{128}$'", "field": "Authorization", "instance": "Bearer"}} in /home/yelp.php on line 70
```

The API key is exactly 128 characters long "IxxU...YXYx", and I copied and pasted it perfectly into both environments. I'm not doing anything special or custom. I didn't make any changes to either environment outside of pasting in that exact API Key string. I even refreshed the API Key to get a new one, and repeated both tests with the new API Key. Failed everywhere again. So what on earth could be the problem? Ugh. Thanks.

Comment: An API key generally isn't the same as a bearer token. I'm not familiar with this specific API though - perhaps you can give us a link to the documentation? Just on the off chance that sample script isn't right or something...it hasn't been updated for a few years, I noticed

Comment: Documentation: https://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v3/authentication

Comment: Hm, it's unconventional but it does seem to be what they're expecting. Strange, not sure thre's much we can do for you. I can only guess that either somehow you pasted it wrong, or you set up the PostMan request wrong, or you somehow didn't copy the PHP code right. It seems less likely that the documentation and sample are wrong, since they both agree. It would be a big issue for the provider if they got something as important as that wrong.

Comment: I downloaded the PHP script as is. It's unchanged. The Postman request was preset in the system. All I had to do was literally paste in my API code and click run. The fact that I have nothing custom anywhere is what makes this so perplexing and frustrating. I also have working API code that I use with other services, and modifying that to Yelp connection information yields the same result. I'm stuck before I even got started.

Comment: I think you need to get support from the API maintainers in the first instance, then